# Does it make sense to convert Vec<Vec<u8>> to Vec<BoundedVec<u8, DescriptionLimit>>?

Tags: substrate-node-template, storage, boundedvec

I have a scenario where I have to store multiple strings. For single string, we can use `BoundedVec<u8, DescriptionLimit>`, that's why I converted `Vec<u8>` into `BoundedVec<u8, DescriptionLimit>` to follow substrate best practices. But how do we store multiple strings?

Does it make sense to convert `Vec<Vec<u8>>` to `Vec<BoundedVec<u8, DescriptionLimit>>`?

Can someone please help me to answer this?

Comment: Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, you are right to use BoundedVec to follow best substrate practices, I recommend this StackExchange questions to learn the difference between BoundedVec and Vec: [When to use BoundedVec vs. WeakBoundedVec vs. Vec?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1152/when-to-use-boundedvec-vs-weakboundedvec-vs-vec).

I am not sure what is your data structure you want to store for the two strings but what I did was to use a struct.
See the example of storing two strings: first name and last name:

```
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Default, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen, PartialEqNoBound, RuntimeDebug)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]
#[codec(mel_bound())]
pub struct Nickname<T: Config> {
    pub first: BoundedVec<u8, T::MaxLength>,
    pub last: Option<BoundedVec<u8, T::MaxLength>>,
}
```

And then store the struct in your storage.

You can see the full example of the code here: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/alexd10s/how-to-storage-migration-example/pallets/nicks/src/lib.rs#L113